# Could not connect to MySQL Server: Unable to connect to localhost

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm new to Mysql.
I'm trying to connect to a remote server to create a Mysql database from Mysql workbench.
Here are the screenshots of the problem.
Any suggestions? I've been roaming whole internet but couldn't find a solution yet...[image]

When I try to test connection, it says that "Could not connect to MySQL Server: Unable to connect to localhost"
Well, i'm not trying to connect my default local host anyway. I'm confused...

Comment: It's highly unlikely that a MySQl server is directly accessible on the internet. If it's accessible at all you'll probably need a SSH login.

Comment: i have connected to the remote server with SSH, by using PuTTY

Comment: Change the connection type to Standard TCP/IP over SSH, then use the details for your PuTTY session to configure it. Then you should be able to use `localhost` and port 3306 to connect to the MySQL server.